# Dynamic output cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I wonder if there are any cache engines or if someone has a good solution that can handle these requirements:

- It should store plain HTML fragments of a page like the standard Output cache in asp.net
- The HTML may contain dynamic content from a database
- When an object is updated in the database all the cached HTML fragment containing that particular object should be destroyed and re-cached next time it will be requested.

There is a separate admin tool to handle all data in the database so I can easy store the Id’s in a cachetable when an object is invalid. I can also make a request to a page that destroy all cached HTML fragment for that object.

But when I write the markup, how could I do to store and retrieve a particular segment from the cache? Of cause I could do this in code behind and have the markup in a string but I don’t want that. I want to have the markup as intact as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is all within an ASP .Net page.  I think your situation is simple enough to where you can write this caching mechanism yourself:

- Make your SQL query as usual
- Use the results to output your aspx page
- Store the results in a static variable or static "Cache" class, this should persist from request to request

Future requests would use your stored results, unless they are invalidated as you mention they would be.  (In my experience, a 1 minute time expiration can work well).

If you want to get more complicated, and preserve the cache even if IIS is restarted:  You could easily use an XmlSerializer and write your results to a file instead of using static variables.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems to consider:

Number 1: Cache invalidation.  This can be solved using cache dependencies (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency.aspx ) which will allow things to be invalidated and recached as data changes (automatically!).

Number 2: Cache storage.  For this, just use the standard ASP.Net cache API using HttpContext.Current.Cache (or a suitable abstraction).  That supports the dependency system as mentioned above.

The ASP.Net cache implementation is pluggable so you can change the storage mechanism between in memory, files, SQL databases, Memcached (via Enyim) or Microsoft Velocity for example.  Each cache store has different reliability that you can pick and choose based on your requirements.